# Trouble with Datagridview.ClearSelection()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want my (readonly,fullrowselect) datagridviews to have no selected rows when the form is loaded. I tried `.ClearSelection` in the forms constructor after setting their datasource but it doesn't work (i would really like to know why...).

Then I tried in the `Form_load` event but it won't clear the selection on the datagridviews I have placed on the not immediately visible tab containers.

Am I doing something wrong? I could do it in the `Layout` event of each tab page but then it will deselect the rows every time the user changes tab, which is not a desired behavior.

Comment: can you edit and put some of your code, maybe seeing it we can help you better ;)

Comment: i don't think its really necessary, maybe i'll try giving a more practical explanation:

Comment: I have 3 datagridview's in a form (2 are inside a preselected tab page, the other is in another tab page) and i want them to appear with no rows selected. It should have been as simple as dgv1.ClearSelection();dgv2.ClearSelection();etc... but when i do this in the constructor, the dgvs always appear with the first row selected. If i do it in the FormLoad event, the dgv in the other tab view will still have its first row selected when i change tabs...

Answer (score 19):

I found out that it's not working in `FormLoad` but works fine in `FormShown`.
So you only have to set your `dataGridView1.ClearSelection` in your `FormShown` and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for this! I almost destroyed my computer because of this frustration. LOL! This happened to me after working wih MDI.

Comment: In my testing case scenario, I was using a btnLoadGrid.PerformClick() call at the end and it was causing the same issue. I was going insane trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Try call an

```
yourGridView.Update();
```

after calling the

```
ClearSelection();
```

to redraw the grid.

Answer (score 0):

It works but there is a slight flicker.

```
    YourDataGridView.DataSource = yourModelList;

    Task.Delay(50).ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            YourDataGridView.ClearSelection();
        }));
    });
```